# jQuery .slideUp() stuttering in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a couple elements in my html document, which I need to hide when I press a button.

```
$(document).on('mouseup','#button',function() {
    setTimeout(setupBox1,100);
    setTimeout(setupBox2,Math.floor((Math.random() * 3000) + 800));
    setTimeout(setupBox3,Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 600));
    $start.fadeOut(300);
    $setbutton.slideUp(300);
    $about.slideUp({duration:400,queue:false}).fadeOut(300);
    $pause.delay(300).fadeIn(300);
    $crossbutton.slideUp(300);
    $settings.fadeOut(300);
}
```

There is also a couple of other things happening. My problem is that in Chrome, the animations (.slideUp() - .fadeOut() is fine) stutter. This will happen about 3/10 times, but is pretty annoying, considering all other browsers (Opera, Firefox, IE, Edge) have no trouble whatsoever. Even my phone (s4 mini) completes the animations without stuttering every single time, it's just something about desktop Chrome(dev).

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't use queue for `slideUp()`. That's said, you have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue...

Comment: That is so that the element fades out as it is sliding up, it looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried normal chrome (no dev)? Not long ago I've installed Chrome Canary and some CSS was working incorrectly on some sites.

Comment: That did it, thank you :). I didn't think about it because I never had issues with Chrome dev before.